# Loop variable of loop over rows must be a record variable or list of scalar variables error in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm converting oracle procedure to PostgreSQL procedure. While converting I'm getting error like.
**loop variable of loop over rows must be a record variable or list of scalar variables
LINE 219:           FOR IDX IN**
I have converted like this is this correct way please help me to solve this error.

```
 FOR IDX IN 
          (SELECT *
                        FROM CUSTINQRESPACDTL
                       WHERE ENTITY_NUM = '1'
                         AND CUST_ID = P_CUST_CODE
                         AND SRV_REF_NUM =
                             (SELECT MAX(SRV_REF_NUM)
                                FROM CUSTINQRESPACDTL
                               WHERE ENTITY_NUM = '1'
                                 AND CUST_ID = P_CUST_CODE)
                         AND SCHEME_TYPE IN ('SBA', 'CAA', 'ODA')) LOOP
          
            IF TRIM(P_BEN_AC_NUM) = IDX.ACC_NUM THEN
              P_SUC_FLAG := 'F';
              P_ERROR    := 'BENREG023';
            END IF;
          END LOOP;
```

Comment: so what is the definition/declaration of the variable `idx` ?

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of context, but to me, the code you have shown doesn't seem to require a loop to begin with (and the sub-query with `= (select max(...) ..)` can probably be simplified using `distinct on ()` in Postgres